# Does CKEditor have tools to automatically download plugins and dependencies

Tags: ckeditor

When building CKEditor I specify plugins in `build-config.js`, however I have to manually download plugins and their dependencies from [addon's page](http://ckeditor.com/addon/clipboard) and put them into `/plugins` page before running `build.sh` script. Does CKEditor have any tool that can do it automatically, like npm for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor 4 - no, it pre-dates most of the packaging tools on the market, or at least the time that they got really popular.

You can also generate a custom build online, through [CKBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder), either choosing plugins from the list of "Available Plugins" or uploading your `build-config.js` there (a button in the top-right corner).

I'm aware this is not the same level of build automation that `npm` offers, but hope this will help. CKEditor 5 will be much better aligned to more modern building tools.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm creating a custom build with additional parameters like `--leave-js-unminified`, so I can't use online builder